# Basic "Hello World" Spring Boot application in IDEA doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I can't decide if there is a problem with the instructions in the spring.io tutorial or if there's something wrong with IDEA. Some help would be nice.

I'm following a [guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) at spring.io to create a simple blog application. I've used the spring initializr to create the application as directed (using Gradle, JDK 1.8, Kotlin) and I cannot run the application from a Spring Boot Run/Debug Configuration. It works only when I run the gradle "bootRun" task, but running through IntelliJ yields a Whitelabel Error Page.

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

Additionally, the Spring Boot output in my console shows that the `MustacheAutoConfiguration` class could not find the `/templates/` folder in my classpath.

```
2019-11-19 13:06:07.136  WARN 11840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
```

My Spring Boot Run/Debug configuration for BlogApplication has "Use classpath of module: blog.main".

Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: do you have created your template folder? Is there your template in it?

Comment: Yes. As I had mentioned, it works when I use it through gradle. So all of the required pieces are at least there.

Answer (score 1):

Did run the application after cloning from the github source. It runs just fine from intellj idea. Tested on JDK 13, 11 and 8

[image: enter code here]

and the configuration for Boot run from intellj idea is bellow. 
[image]

So I would suggest checking your gradle configuration of intelljidea.

Comment: It looks like it may be a problem with the auto-generated .idea project folder when I create the project. If I delete the folder and re-import the gradle project it works. I'll need to figure out what exactly the difference is when I have more time.

Comment: This is a known issue apparently. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221673

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue at the moment. See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221673